# Linux bootup only with USB dongle

Tags: boot, usb, security, authentication, two-factor-authentication

I am currently trying to figure out if there is a way to make Linux only boot if a specific USB dongle is present in one of the USB ports.

I tried to find a solution on the internet but couldn't find anything. Has anybody done this already or knows how to do it or where to even start looking?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can add an init script checking for a particular USB device serial number or even a particular file on the thumb drive (is that what you call dongle?) and halting the system if the required element wasn't found.

[This page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_startup_process) references various config files and scripts used during startup process. Personally I would start by creating an init.d script which I'm sure is running at the point where USB is operational.